# Recommended way of sharing an object between C# processes

Tags: c#, ipc

I have read numerous different things about IPC between 2 C# applications and their pros and cons, but don't feel like I have reached a satisfactory answer yet for my use case.

I have an object that already exists that will change frequently (I am trying to attach my tool to a game and use it to debug elements created with the tool). As a result, I don't beleive serialisation is appropriate as I would essentially be serialising/de-serialsing the object 60 times a second for no good reason. As a result, piping is not possible (or am I missing something here?).

As the game is running in Unity, I am limited to .NET 3.5 technologies so can't use the new .NET4 shared memory class.

So it seemed like .NET remoting is the way to go. It is less than ideal - I have no need for network support, the object I want to share is in memory, no real reason for the overhead of using proxies and sending messages to change it.

However, [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14791/NET-Remoting-with-an-easy-example) which everyone links to doesn't seem to be good - the source code doesn't compile and when I got it to compile it crashed. The tutorial itself makes no reference to the Cache class which seems central and I can't see, even with the source code, how it would fit in with my application. Is there a better resource? Is this really the best approach.

Finally I am left with interpolating with C++ to use the unmanaged functionality of creating a shared memory and moving the object into it. Before I go down that rabbit hole, I wanted to confirm they really isn't a better way.

**Update - Some more information**

At the moment just trying things out so 2 console applications. However, in the end I have one C#/Winforms application (this *is* is .NET 4.0 if that helps) which I will connect to the Unity process (which obviously I have no control over). I have a DLL which is used by both the tool and Unity. I was going to have a class in that which would allow the tool to access the objects (e.g. if I could use pipes, from Unity I'd call into this class to create the pipe and then connect to the pipe from the tool).

The objects themselves represent essentially a finite state machine whose description is loaded from an XML file. It would be possible to recreate the object from a very minimal amount of data. However, I would rather avoid hand coding a solution that uses some kind of event/message system to keep the objects in sync with regard to which state is active etc.

Comment: Quick question: what are the two apps in question?  (ie: target is executable compiled from unity, tool is forms exe, etc)  Note: I'd probably just try and hook code into the target app in this case which launches a thread I'd then have local control over and access to the rest of the target...  Thread could report back to caller at interval however I like.

Comment: @All thanks for all the answers, I will review them and consider what will work best. Having read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6091685/958004) answer I see that having a shared memory may not be enough for the reasons listed which moves me back a square or 2...

Comment: @ebyrob Could you elaborate on what you mean/how one would go about hooking code in on the fly? If I am understanding you right, that sounds potentially very good.

Comment: It kind of depends on what's available to you.  If you're in a plug-in of the game, you're pretty golden.  If there's just nothing provided, then things hearken back to the days of dependency injection...  You replace something already being called with your own code which wraps a) the expected stuff, b) your extra stuff.  (not really related to the inter-process part) Note: there's also the system debugger and runtime debugging facilities which can get you some traction.

Comment: Microsoft considers remoting to be deprecated (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/72x4h507.aspx)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of data are we talking about here? If it is symbols / metrics, it could be delimited and stored in a memory mapped file and shared.

Since you're on 3.5, you can't use the MMF file directly, but FileMap should work for you

https://github.com/tomasr/filemap/tree/master

Comment: I used the FileMap in the end as NamedPipes do not appear to be available in whatever version of Mono Unity uses. I also used [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7851/A-C-Framework-for-Interprocess-Synchronization-and) for synchronising access to the memory mapped file.

Answer (score 2):

I think WCF with [NetNamedPipeBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) would be an easier/better option.

Example [here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication).

Comment: This would seem to be ideal, however, I am having issues in combining it with Unity. I get a TypeLoad exception on various types from within the ServiceModel DLL (despite me copying the DLLs in to the Unity project) So this may be out of the question...

Comment: Thanks for the info! I wan't sure how it would work with Unity directly, but Named Pipes looked like the easiest option. Do update if you find a solution, it will be a new thing to learn.

Comment: Just to let you know I had to go with MemoryMappedFile as yeah, looks like Unity does not like NetNamedPipes. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

In my company we are using a solution that is a Combination of XML object Serialisation and the [FileSytemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that is more or less the same as named Pipes but it is fast and its working well.

Comment: I would like to avoid serialising the object in any way as there could be many of these objects and they would all be changing 60 times a second so even a binary serialisation would cause a serious overhead. I want my tool to be essentially in real time, reflecting the current state of the object. Thanks

Comment: @T.Kiley `60 times a second` is nothing for a decent computer.

Comment: Hmm, ok I assumed it would be, in that case, I could just use pipes and a BinarySerialiser...

Comment: Using Disk I/O for IPC is more of a quick and dirty solution than "the right way" to do IPC.  You're basically adding an unnecessary middleman (the disk system) to your communication.  Easy to set up, but if there will be a lot of communication, I recommend against it.

Comment: Yes maybe, but even named pipes are working with hd IO and the commen Tenor is that named pipes are the "right way" and depend of the project time and cost it is ( i am now talking just for my Company ) Accepcable solution

Comment: You were right, serialising all this stuff was no big deal. In the end, I used a memory mapped file and dump all the data I need every frame.