# Given a memory address, is it possible to create an object from it?

Tags: c#, pointers, memory

In C#, if I create a hash table and get the memory address it's stored in, can I use that memory address in a different part of the program to recreate the hash table?

For example, can i do something like:

```
HashTable hash = new HashTable(oldHashPointer);
```

Comment: In what language? What do you mean "recreate"?

Comment: In C#, and I mean something like "HashTable ht = new HashTable(intptr)", which should create a copy of the hash table that's at that address.

Comment: A valid object address in C# is always located in the GC heap.  That address can only ever stay valid if the object is *pinned* so that the GC cannot collect or move the object.  GCHandle is required, a pointer is never good enough.  You can always recover the object reference with the GCHandle.Target property.  The `unsafe` keyword means what it says, using pointers doesn't go wrong often enough.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. This isn't possible in C# in the way that you're describing it. For example the following code:

```
HashTable a = new HashTable();
HashTable b = a;
```

is essentially what you are trying to do, without **explicit** pointer usage. `HashTable b` isn't a seperate entity, it's a pointer to the reference stored in `HashTable a`, which points to a `HashTable` object in memory.

[This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx) elaborates on this. A quote from the page:

> Pointer types do not inherit from object and no conversions exist
>   between pointer types and object. Also, boxing and unboxing do not
>   support pointers.

**However**, if you're trying to share objects between processes (in this case, a `HashTable`), you could look into [Memory Mapped Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx). These will essentially allow you to write a serialized object into a virtual "file" residing in memory, that is also accessible from the other process. However, this is only available in .NET 4.0 or newer.

Comment: So given the memory address, is there a way to create a reference to it?  e.g. HashTable b = new HashTable(address);

Comment: No, you cannot convert a reference pointer into an object. This MSDN page elaborates on that; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx. Where are you getting this `address` from in the first place?

Comment: I have a hash table in Process A, and I'm trying to read it from Process B.  I can pass the memory address of the hash table to Process B.  I know there's other methods, but I'm specifically trying to get this method to work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031138/recommended-way-of-sharing-an-object-between-c-sharp-processes This question might be able to help you. For a personal touch, my go-to method would be a `FileSystemWatcher` in the `TEMP` directory and just write the serialized data in there, and watch it from both processes. Also, I believe you'll run into issue with process address violations if you try something like what you're suggesting in your original question.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx You could also look into Memory Mapped Files.

Comment: I'll take a look at the memory mapped files.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem! If my answer helped, feel free to select this answer as the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. How to do it:

1. Your class have to be marked with
   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] or (LayoutKind.Explicit)
2. You should allocate in unmanaged memory needed amount of bytes var ptr =
   Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)));
3. Copy your object to that pointer Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr,
   false);
4. Create newObj and copy data to that object Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, newObj);
5. Don't forget to free unmanaged memory or you'll get memory leaks
   Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

**Update:**

[Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ar5qmK):

```
namespace MarhsalExampe
{
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    public class Program
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public class SomeClass
        {
            public int IntProp { get; private set; }
            public string StrProp { get; private set; }
            public double DoubleProp { get; private set; }
            public bool BoolProp { get; private set; }

            public SomeClass() { }
            public SomeClass(int i, string s, double d, bool b)
            {
                IntProp = i;
                StrProp = s;
                DoubleProp = d;
                BoolProp = b;
            }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("HashCode: {0}, IntProp: {1}, StrProp: {2}, DoubleProp: {3}, BoolProp: {4}",
                    GetHashCode(), IntProp, StrProp, DoubleProp, BoolProp);
            }
        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            var obj = new SomeClass(42, "42", 42.0, true);
            Console.WriteLine("Obj is: {0}", obj);

            IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                // Allocate memory in unmanaged memory
                ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SomeClass)));
                // Copy data to ptr
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, false);
                Console.WriteLine("Pointer: 0x{0:X}", ptr.ToInt64());

                // Create new object
                var newObj = new SomeClass();
                Console.WriteLine("newObj before updating from pointer: {0}", newObj);
                // Copy data to new object
                Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, newObj);

                Console.WriteLine("newObj after updating: {0}", newObj);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: OP is trying to access a HashTable from a different process. I think it'll throw a process address range violation if the other process tries to read from the `ptr`.

Comment: @ext0, for reading another process private memory, one can use [ReadProcessMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx). The process must have [PROCESS_VM_READ process right](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms684880(v=vs.85).aspx) and also started under admin rights and SeDebugPrivilege.

Answer (score -1):

C# is reference based, meaning you can create multiple variables pointing to the same instance.

ext10 already gave a nice example for it. So adding something in `hasttable a`, then it's also available for `b`. Because they are the same instance.