# Store data in cache/ram without destroying them at the end of the program

Tags: c#, .net, caching, memory, ram

As I said in the title, I'm trying to put in memory an object without killing it at the end of the program,
the main idea it's, if the object isn't in memory, the program create it at the beginning, but if it is, the program retrieve all the data of the object.
here is an exemple with  System.Runtime.Caching;

```
    class CachingTest
    {
        private static string WORDWRAPKEY = "WrapperWord";

        public string value { get; set; }
        public string data = "data to store";

        public CachingTest()
        {
            ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
            if (cache.Contains(WORDWRAPKEY))
                value = "EXIST";
            else
            {
                CacheItemPolicy cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
                cacheItemPolicy.AbsoluteExpiration = ObjectCache.InfiniteAbsoluteExpiration;
                cache.Add(WORDWRAPKEY, data, cacheItemPolicy);
                value = "CREATE";
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CachingTest test = new CachingTest();
            Console.WriteLine("Data value statement: " + test.value);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

The fact is, t
he statement is always "CREATE" and never exist, So I can Assume the cache is killed when the pregram ends.
Is there any way to store data in memory without destrying it at the end of the program ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we share the data using shared memory segment with "Object" between two managed processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090534/how-can-we-share-the-data-using-shared-memory-segment-with-object-between-two)

Comment: You're looking for _persistent data storage_. RAM is not persistent, if the program ends or the computer turns off - it's cleared. Use a file, database, or something more permanent.

Comment: The operating system clears all memory that is returned to it before handing it to another program. Even if it weren't the case, memory is allocated by pages, it would probably end up at a different address. Even if that weren't the case, the .net VM would not use the same address again for the variable. If you want persistence, write it to disk, a database, registry...

Comment: Yes, if the computer turns off, I will create it again, that's not a problem. I want to keep the data until the computer turns off

Comment: You could implement the IDisposable or a "Finalize" Destructor  on the CachingTest class, so when the program turn off you can save the cache on a file ou permanent database?

Answer (score 0):

As @gunr2171 said, you are using a [MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) so you are explicitly caching items only in the current application instance. If you want different behaviour then you should implement your own cache type just like [System.Runtime.Caching.ObjectCache Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.objectcache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#remarks) says.

Comment: Yes, Caching was a try, and I used it as an exemple, but as far as I read, that's not the solution